# Is there a performance impact for queries traversing one-to-one relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, query-performance

Consider that I have an entity A which is defined like this

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @OneToOne
    private B b;

    // getters & setters
}
```

and B which is defined like this:

```
@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    private String x;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Let's also assume that `x` is indexed. My question is whether there's a general "noticeable" performance difference between querying for `x` from A like this:

```
TypedQuery<A> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a where a.b.x = :x", A.class);
query.setParameter("x", "myX");
A a = query.getSingleResult();
```

and querying for `x` from B directly like this:

```
TypedQuery<Person> q = entityManager.createQuery("select b from B b where b.x = :x", B.class);
q.setParameter("x", "myX");
B b = query.getSingleResult();
```

If it matters we're using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Sure, because you're running two queries in the first case. Your entity manager needs to load the instance of B into A when you run the first query. Turn on show_sql option to see what I mean

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.